# Does the "re" in emails have an ancient origin?

Tags: etymology, idiom, example-request, ablative, epistula

The Latin ablative *re* has become a word in English, meaning "regarding" or "with reference to" or something along those lines.
This is also used in emails as an automatically generated prefix "Re: " to replies.
Was the word *re* used in a similar fashion in antiquity, to indicate the topic at the start of a letter or a passage?
In other words, did Romans use *re* in the same meaning as we do today in English?

Comment: Is *re* usually meant to stand in for *reply* in emails?

Comment: Cause if it is, then I somewhat doubt Romans (back when letters were of course written and could have taken days to deliver) would have had a need to clarify that their letters were responses to an original letter - it would have been obvious that certain letters came in a certain temporal order, or at least easier to keep track of than nowadays, when we receive hundreds of emails a week and can't possibly keep a mental ordering of all our correspondences. (But that's still all speculation on my part - they could have used *re* for all I know)...

Comment: @Nick, I have been informed that the *re* is not short for "reply" or "response", but really is the word *re*. It practically means "reply to" in email titles, however.

Comment: I actually think the *Re:* in e-mails (like *Fw:*) is of a different origin than the *re* used outside e-mail, in formal English.

Comment: @Nick In the 1970s, I was first told that "Re" on (paper, carbon copy, and mimeograph) letters was the Latin word, meaning "the matter". I read the same thing in many places before email began. The contemporary understanding as an abbreviation of "Reply" is a misunderstanding, though today it prevails. Before the switch, you would not see "Re" and "Subject" at the top of the same letter, since that would be redundant.

Comment: @BenKovitz oh wow, didn't know that -- latin's everywhere!

Answer (score 11):

Yes, it does have an ancient origin. See [RFC 5332](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322) (3.6.5):

> When used in a reply, the field body MAY start with the
> string "Re: " (an abbreviation of the Latin "in re", meaning "in the
> matter of") followed by the contents of the "Subject:" field body of
> the original message.  If this is done, only one instance of the
> literal string "Re: " ought to be used since use of other strings or
> more than one instance can lead to undesirable consequences.

Comment: Thanks, but this does not exactly answer my question. I wanted to know if the word *re* (with or without preposition) was used in a similar meaning in ancient times. To me at least *re* makes sense without a preposition as well, but I would rather let attested ancient usage be the judge of that.

Comment: Interesting! I always thought *Re:* was from *Reply*, just as *Fwd:* is from *Forward*, but apparently not.

Comment: Huh, I thought it meant "Regarding", since I've also seen it used in memo titles ("Re: The bicycle shed")

Comment: I never would have guessed that there is actually an RFC for that!

Comment: I've never imagined *re* in emails stood for *reply*.! I used it in business all my life, in the sense of *in reference to your complaint /request /question* etc. **Never** thought it meant *reply*. Never too old to learn ;-)

Answer (score 8):

*Re* was certainly used with the same meaning, as stendarr points out in another answer, but it was not used in the same manner.  For example, Cicero did not start his letters with it, although there are examples of him using the word with the meaning "in the matter of."

There are many references in ancient texts showing the use of the word *res* in the ablative with the meaning "in the matter of."  The Romans used *res* much like we use the word "thing" and they used it frequently.  Even our word "republic" is from *res publica* which literally means "the public thing."

In a crazy sci-fi world where the Romans had email, I think using *re* just as we do would be completely consistent and appropriate.

Edit: From Cicero's letters:

1. [*in hac re*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.02.0017%3Abook%3D1%3Aletter%3D1%3Asection%3D2) translated as "[in this matter](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.02.0022%3Atext%3DQ%20FR%3Abook%3D1%3Aletter%3D1%3Asection%3D1)"

I found abundant other examples among Cicero's letters of his use of *re* which I think could hold a meaning like what we're discussing, but this was the only one for which I was able to match the Latin text to an existing translation.

These examples are all in the body of his letters as he directs the reader's attention to some matter they've previously discussed.  *Re* does not ever occur as a sort of subject line like we use it.  There's also the example I mentioned in the comments.

Comment: Can you give some ancient examples where *re* means "in the matter of"? With such examples this answer would be great.

Comment: I have an immediately available snippet of a quote here in my dictionary that shows `ea re` from Cicero and gives the translation as "on that account," which I think fits the bill here.  I'll spend a little more time today and tomorrow to see if I can dig up any other examples.

Comment: Ok, good. In questions like this it really makes a difference to give explicit quotes with links to some online text corpus (some include English translations) for wider context. I'll wait and see what you found.

Comment: Added an edit with another example.

Comment: Thanks. (+1) I still wonder if *re* (or *ea re* or *hac re*) occurs without prepositions. It can be grammatically valid without a preposition, and it seems that in modern usage a preposition is never used.

Answer (score 1):

From the OED
Originally: in the matter of, referring to; in re (*see in re prep.*). Subsequently: about, concerning.

Etymology: < classical Latin rē, ablative of rēs thing, affair (*see res n.1*).
The use as a preposition was formerly much criticized in usage guides. See e.g. H. W. Fowler Mod. Eng. Usage (1926) 255/2, and compare quot. 1935, which parodies this use.

The form re. probably results from reanalysis as showing an abbreviation for *regarding prep*.

*in re prep.*:   Chiefly Law. In the matter of, referring to. Usually followed by a name. Cf. re prep.

*Res n.1*:  Law. Any thing in respect of which a person may claim a right.

*regarding prep*:   In reference or relation to; about, concerning.